# Textures broken after importing to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, textures, dds-format

I made some trees in TreeIt tree generator and imported it to Unity. It was fine until I converted dds files to jpg files and it started doing this:

[image: screenshot]

I know it has something to do with transpanency, but I don´t know how to fix it. I also have exported some other textures from editor, that I don´t understand how to use (like the ones with purple colors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JPG** can't support transparency because it uses **RGB** color space. You should use a format that allows transparency, like **PNG**.

Comment: Yess! That was it!